# highcharts - exported png in horizontal bar charts

Tags: highcharts

I have a horizontal bar chart with negative and positive values,
I noticed that gridlines have a slight offset to the left (maybe they get rounded?). Here is an image that illustrates my problem:
[image]

I tried to reproduce it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/g32tyuxd/), but got slightly different result (please export png to see the image). It's hard to notice but negative bars don't start from zero.  [image]

So I am curios to know what is the root cause of the problem and potential fix you may suggest.
Thanks in advance!

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {

        type: 'bar',
        styledMode: true,
        events: {
        load: function(){
            const chart = this;
          const gridLines = chart.yAxis[0].gridGroup.element.querySelectorAll('path');
            console.log(gridLines);
            const yTicks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks;
            for(let tick of Object.keys(yTicks)){
              if(yTicks[tick].pos === 0) {
                const zeroGridLine = yTicks[tick].gridLine.element;
                zeroGridLine.classList.replace('highcharts-grid-line','zero-line');
                if(chart.seriesGroup) chart.seriesGroup.element.appendChild(zeroGridLine)
                break;
              }
  }
        }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'title'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Medical care',
'Shelter',
'Personal services',
'Education',
'Furnishings',
'Communication',
'Recreation',
'Fuels and utilities',
'Apparel',
'Transportation',],
        lineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
        align: 'left',
        reserveSpace: true,
        step: 1,
        x:-5,
/*         max: 9.5,
        min: -0.5, */
        style: {
        whiteSpace: 'wrap',
        textOverflow: 'visible'
        }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {


        tickWidth: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'April 2020',
        data: [
           4.81, 2.62, 2.53, 2.15, 1.31, 1.12, 0.94, -0.35, -3, -8]
    }, {
        name: 'Jan 2020',
        data: [4.48, 3.32, 2.11, 2.17, 0.66, 0.93, 1.41, 0.57, -1.26, 2.87]
    }]
    })
```

```css
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.highcharts-xaxis-labels {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.zero-line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is a bug. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread or add your own opinion about this behaviour. The core developers will respond you.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14302